# Saving files internal

Tags: android, file, save, output

I was following an [Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) tutorial on saving files, from Google, when I came across this code:

```
String filename = "myfile";
String string = "Hello world!";
FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
  outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  outputStream.write(string.getBytes());
  outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The "openFileOutput" gives an error saying is "undefined" so i created a

```
Context fileContext;
```

On the same method, but it gives an error saying i should initialize it. How should i initialize it? Or should i declare it in the class, because if i take it out of the method and declared it in the class it won´t give me an error.

My Code:

```
public class DataManager
{
private static DataManager _instance;
private Context fileContext;
public String[] arraySentences;

private DataManager()
{}

public static DataManager getInstance()
{
    if (_instance == null)
    {
        _instance = new DataManager();
    }

    return _instance;
}

public void saveSentences(String jsonData)
{
    String filename = "myfile";
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try
    {
        outputStream = fileContext.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(jsonData.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where did you place this code, Post your complete code

Comment: your class should extend Activity. or it needs to get the context from the activity

Comment: I´m building a singleton, not an activity. I shouldn´t extend to activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way..

```
public void createFile(Context c) throws IOException{
     String FILENAME = timeStamp();
     String string = "hello world!";

     FileOutputStream fos = c.openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(string.getBytes());
    fos.close();


}
```

call above mthod

```
createFile(myActivity.this);
```

Comment: In my case, i want to received the string to save.

Comment: What do i pass as Context?

Comment: your activity name like: createFile(myActivityname.this); or use getapplicationcontext();

Comment: Okay, was having trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

It's supposed you declare this method inside a class that extends Context, like Activity, so you can call it without declaring any aditional Context object.

Regards.

Comment: I´m probably missing that.